# Modify wp-login.php Labels Conditionally Based On Referring URL

Tags: login, conditional-tags, wp-login-form, conditional-content

I apologize if this is an easily answered question - I've been looking for a while and can't quite get my head around it.

I would like to modify the first label for the wp-login.php page based on the potential user. My current plan is to use url parameters to differentiate users, have a function that checks for a parameter then returns the appropriate label.

Currently, this function does successfully change the username field label:

```
add_filter(  'gettext', array($this, 'register_text' ) );
add_filter(  'ngettext', array($this, 'register_text')  );
public function register_text( $translating ) {
     $translated = str_ireplace(  'Username or Email Address',  'Warranty Registration Number',  $translating );
     return $translated;
}
```

But I am struggling to make this conditional. My last attempt looked like this:

```
public function register_text( $translating ) {
    $para_log = $_GET['param']
    $s14 = 's14'
    $p32 = 'p32'

            if ($para_log == $s14) {
                 $translated = str_ireplace(  'Username or Email Address',  'Dealer Number',  $translating );
             return $translated;

            } elseif ($para_log == $p32) {
                 $translated = str_ireplace(  'Username or Email Address',  'Distributor Number',  $translating );
            return $translated;

            } else {
                 $translated = str_ireplace(  'Username or Email Address',  'Registration Number',  $translating );
            return $translated;
            }
    endif;

}
```

But this crashes the page. I'm hoping I just suck and it's a syntax error I can't see.

I've also tried variations of this, but no luck here either:

```
   function login_function() {
add_filter( 'gettext', 'username_change', 20, 3 );
function username_change( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) 
{
    if ($text === 'Username') 
    {
        $translated_text = 'customLoginName';
    }
    return $translated_text;
}

add_action( 'login_head', 'login_function' );
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is some syntax errors. on line 2 to 4 you're missing ending semicolons.

And `endif` line is not needed for curly-braces if statement.

Comment: Thank you! With both of those syntax changes the code works perfectly. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a syntax error: the `endif;` statement is to be used to close `if() :` statements, as not using curly braces cannot identify the limits of the blocks:

```php
if($something):
  //code
endif;
```

When using "braces-styled" if-elses you have just to use curly braces:

```php
if($something){
  //code
}else if($somethingElse){
  //more code
} else {
  //even more code
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining! You were right - endif; wasn't needed. I did need some semi colons to end lines 2-4 as the other commenter said as well. Thank you for taking the time.